# Destructor of referenced temporary object

Tags: c++, destructor, c++14

Given example:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <cstdlib>

#define PRINT_NAME { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }

namespace
{

struct A 
{
    A() { PRINT_NAME; }
    ~A() { PRINT_NAME; }
};

A f() { return {}; }

A b;

A && g() { return std::move(b); }

}

int
main()
{ 
    std::cout << "------------------" << std::endl;
    {
        f();
        std::cout << 1 << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "------------------" << std::endl;
    {
        A && a = f();
        // or A const & a = f(); as mentioned in below discussion
        std::cout << 2 << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "------------------" << std::endl;
    {
        A && a = g();
        std::cout << 3 << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "------------------" << std::endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

and its output (of *clang 3.5.0*):

```
(anonymous namespace)::A::A()
------------------
(anonymous namespace)::A::A()
(anonymous namespace)::A::~A()
1
------------------
(anonymous namespace)::A::A()
2
(anonymous namespace)::A::~A()
------------------
3
------------------
(anonymous namespace)::A::~A()
```

What is the semantic rule: an thinkable shortand of the standard's paragraphs, which compactly summarizes the difference in destructors behaviour regarding above code sample? I often faces "idiomatic rules" formulated via the "have some (non-obviously relevant) characteristic" or "have some inherent attribute" statements, e.g. "if it has a name, then it is an lvalue". Is there something similar?

Comment: There's no difference lifetime-wise between binding to an rvalue reference and a const lvalue reference.

Comment: @T.C. Really so. It is unobvious (for me). Sorry, if the question have not sense.

Comment: Paragraph 12.2/5 of the standard.

Comment: @n.m. exactly what I want (seems it cannot be compacted though).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with rvalue references. In fact, if you change `A&&` to `const A&` throughout the code, [the behavior won't change](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9335575fe2558734).

Probably your confusion is caused by the name of `std::move()` function. It doesn't actually move anything, it just casts its argument to rvalue reference.

Don't think about destructors, think about lifetime of objects. Personally I don't know a simple rule of thumb (apart from "read the standard"), but these three rules may help you:

1. Static objects have (basically) lifetime of the whole program.
2. If a temporary object returned from a function is not bound to anything, it's lifetime ends when the whole expression execution finishes.
3. If a temporary object returned from a function is bound to some reference, its lifetime is extended to a lifetime of that reference.

Comment: WRT third clause: if I changing code `A && g() { A && c = f(); return std::move(c); }` then `c.~A()` called on `}` bracket. But reference to temporary object still exists.

Comment: @Orient because in that case the object is destroyed at the end of `g()` (and  it therefore returns a dangling reference).

Comment: You are confused with cause and effect. More precisely you have mentioned the effect not relevant to my question. I just wanted to inform you that third clause is ill-defined and may cause confusion (because it is not true for every case, when temporary object bounded to **any** reference, but only for [specific situations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29205339/destructor-of-referenced-temporary-object#comment46621984_29205339)).

Comment: @Orient In the first clause, an unbound temporary is destroyed immediately. In the second clause, a temporary is bound to a reference so its lifetime is extended. In the third clause, you just reference a static object. So what exactly did I mention that is not relevant to your question?